# Open vsc-workspace extension files in vscode only

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am using ubuntu, I have configured few vscode workspaces. I would like to open the workspace files directly in vscode when I double click them. I have tried setting the default to vs code. However, it is making every plain text file to open in vscode, which I don't like. This is because I generally have text files which can be hundereds of MB and it will crash my system if opened in vscode. Please let me know if some one has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was solved by vscode dev team now.

I am using ubuntu 20.4LTS. With VSCode installed via snap. On latest version as of this answer i.e., 1.49.1.

I have set vscode as default application for opening `.code-workspace` extension files. If you have not set that already, you can do so by:

`Right click on file` >`Properties` > Choose the tab `Open With` > Choose `Visual Studio Code` from the list and click on set as default.

Thanks for the community for closing this. Cheers